# How do I fix the Syntax error, ";" expected but "ELSE" found error in Pascal?

Tags: error-handling, pascal

I'm having some issues with the if..else function when nested. Here's a preview of the code.

```
        If total>10 then
        writeln('You are a great student who loves to study!');
                else;
                if (total>8) and (total<=10) then
                writeln ('You are a good student,just take more practice.');
                else;
                if (total>6) and (total<=8) then
                writeln ('You are an average student. Try harder in all aspects of your study.');
                else;
                writeln ('You are an under-average student. Try even harder!');
        readkey;
        readln;
End.
```

I tried modifying the code, but it doesn't seem to work. Could you assist me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all instances of `else;` with `else` and remove the semicolons before each `else`.

```
  if total > 10 then
    WriteLn('You are a great student who loves to study!')
  else if (total > 8) and (total <= 10) then
    WriteLn ('You are a good student; it just takes more practice.')
  else if (total > 6) and (total <= 8) then
    WriteLn ('You are an average student. Try harder in all aspects of your study.')
  else
    WriteLn ('You are a below-average student. Try even harder!');
  ReadKey;
  ReadLn;
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But after I removed every semicolon after "else", I still get the same problem. It's somewhere at the first "else" of the code.

Comment: The `;` character before `else` must be removed.

Comment: Do you mean the semicolon after the "writeln" command?

Comment: Yes, there are  many of those errors here. See a short tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_if_then_else_statement.htm

Comment: Yes, if you read the tutorial, the last else clause must have a statement ending with a `;`

Comment: @PhúcDuyNguyễn: Sorry, my apologies. I missed that you also had semicolons before `else`, and then I had to leave the computer for some time. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Not meaning to be picky, but strictly "the last else clause must have a statement ending with a ;  *if there is a following statement*"

Comment: @MartynA: Or maybe LU RD implicitly meant "the last else clause [in your snippet] must have a statement ending with a `;`" :)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand:  Sure, of course I wasn't intending to have a dig at LU RD, just wanted to avoid giving the impression that a statement needs a `;` terminator ...